# Spyder (Python 3.6) wkhtmltopdf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer and I ran these import statements last week on my computer without a problem but now this week when I run the following statements in particular the wkhtmltopdf import I run into an error.

```
import pyodbc
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import jinja2
import wkhtmltopdf
from wkhtmltopdf.main import WKhtmlToPdf
import datetime
import calendar
from pathlib import Path
```

This leads to this error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr8Ti.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The project you appear to be using is long dead and never got a Python 3-compatible release.

Comment: Would it be compatible with python 2.*?

Comment: It might be. It might not. It's 8-year-old code. It _probably_ isn't incompatible with Python 2.7, but nobody can promise that for sure. And meanwhile, it may be incompatible with modern versions of wkhtmltopdf or any of the other dependencies, unless you can install 8-year-old versions of all of them as well.